# VDM Joining objects together

Tags: uv, sculpting

So I want to make some VDM's, but instead of sculpting my own I want to join some parts of cliff models to create them, however I'm having trouble merging them together in a way the VDM bake works.

I've tried different bools and remesh, but no matter what I do it doesn't see it as a "sculpted mesh"? I'm guessing it's a UV issue?

TLDR: Trying to add a cliff face model part to become a VDM?